# Is it possible to make a game in the browser using plain HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make a game in the browser based on `divs`, `<imgs>`, HTML5, CSS3, and good ole' jQuery? According to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6106271/339852), browser rendering speed is pretty good these days, which is the only reason I'm even considering this option. Is his answer applicable to creating a game in vanilla HTML?

Comment: CSS3 and jQuery are NOT vanilla HTML.

Comment: When I said vanilla HTML I meant just plain HTML as opposed to `<canvas>`, Prototype.js, Raphael, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [DHTML games](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/tetris/) have been around for over a decade and HTML 5 provides fairly advanced rendering via the `CANVAS`. Check out Microsoft's rendering examples for the [IE engine](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/) to see the type of performance you can expect (some things perform better than others--most are very impressive).

Check out this little [HTML 5 MMO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_WZqhu082A) project and [Illyriad](http://www.illyriad.co.uk/) (which claims to be HTML 5 based).

Is it possible to write a game without the `CANVAS` element? Visually, you will be limited but logic can still be sophisticated. A game engine should be based on high-performance structures, not on DOM elements. For example, if you were calculating collision on a 2D field, you might evaluate a matrix and redraw only the impacted elements. You should not evaluate the position of DOM elements, as this will be very slow.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links! I'll give my idea(s) a shot, then. I've actually been doing some testing on my own, and it seems pretty decent. I've actually got ~3150 `p` elements on a page with frequently changing CSS attribues (a tile map, if you must know). It performs perfectly!

Comment: @ElliotBonneville - 3000 elements isn't that many and modern browser engines are incredibly smart. As long as you aren't constantly iterating through all the elements it should perform fine (see my edit about using simple structures to perform calculations).

Comment: This is cool. :) Thanks for the information. Can I ask what you mean by 'evaluate a matrix'? A few links or something would be fine.

Comment: Take the old Super Mario games for example. You can represent the position of the character, the ground, enemies, ladders, etc. with a 2 dimensional JavaScript array (a matrix). When you need to perform a calculation (e.g. did the player just run into an enemy?) you examine the matrix to see where each element is. Once you have a result, you can update just the impacted DOM elements. This will be much faster than looping through all the DOM elements and asking them for their position.

Comment: There are many posts on 2D arrays on this site (starting with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. Yeah, that's what I would do, I just didn't understand your terminology. I'd never heard that 2D array = matrix, although I suppose that's pretty obvious in hindsight. =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Theres an HTML5 Angry Birds, Cut the Rope, even Pac-man.

Comment: What are my limits? E.g. what's the max amount of divs I can have on the screen without affecting performance?

Comment: it all depends on the browser and the hardware you are running on.

Comment: Those tend to use HTML5 canvas, not divs and images.

Comment: he said html5 so `canvas` is applicable.

Comment: Nope, no `<canvas>`, sorry. I meant specifically the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally clear what you mean by "Plain HTML" since you also mention HTML5.  If you just mean what can you create in a browser without plug-ins then I would take a look at come of the work being done in Canvas and SVG.  The example that really changed my idea of what is possible is a demo of the CAKE library which you can view [here](http://glimr.rubyforge.org/cake/missile_fleet.html).  Sadly it is beyond IE8 (not sure about IE9 and I can't test it from where I am) but it runs well on an iPad which amazed me.

Comment: By plain HTML, I meant specifically the DOM as opposed to SVG libraries, the `<canvas>` tag, Prototype.js, etc.

Comment: OK great.  Never the less the demo is worth a look as an example of what is becoming possible.

Comment: Agreed, it's really amazing stuff. +1

Answer (score 1):

Strickly using the DOM is possible, but improbable.  I actually wanted to do this, so i was thinking of using the jQuery UI javascript to move items around and perform collision detection, ect...  It would be pretty neet to see a game using strickly dom elements and javascript.

If you have ever played any of those moving the blocks to solve a puzzle game (i do not know what they are called, but i bet its something like "Blocked In") would be very possible with strictly Div elements and Javascript and i would applaud you for such maneuvers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make a game in the browser using plain HTML?

Yes, but it's relatively limited; you wont be making World of Warcraft with complex 3D worlds, audio, and animations without a serious performance hit.

Comment: Well I know *that*. I wasn't even planning on making an MMORPG. I'm guessing you noticed I was fifteen. *sigh*

Comment: There are webgl js libraries like three.js that would allow you to make something like this:  http://triggerrally.com/.  Just don't try it in IE :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Most games like Angry Birds, Fieldrunners etc, use what is called "HTML5" when they use the `canvas` new tag.

Using the DOM to make a game is impossible (unless you're writing pong, and still...). The DOM is way too slow.

A canvas is an element you can manipulate to draw on a bitmap. In javascript.

You should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5883032/851498) to understand the choice of API ot use depending on your use case (DOM vs Canvas vs SVG).

Comment: I understand the differences between the DOM and `<canvas>`. I dabbled with `<canvas>` myself a bit, actually. I just wanted to know if it was possible with specifically the DOM.