# Does it make a difference in browser rendering performance if everything is wrapped in a div?

Tags: html, performance, browser

Say, I'm having a html page with the following (simplified) content within the body:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
</div>
```

opposed to this one:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block3"></div>
</div>
```

Does this make any difference in browser rendering speed? I'm wondering if in the first case the browser needs compute the layout for all three child div's in order to render **wrapper** element.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it should not really affect the performance at all so do whichever is best for what you need.

Also, this question had been answered here: [Does the use of multiple DIVs affect page performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106219/does-the-use-of-multiple-divs-affect-page-performance)

So you can look there for what more people say on it.